# Sending mail via Python with cyrillic characters

Tags: python, smtplib

The problem is in subject. That's ok when I do

```
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
s.starttls() 
s.login(".....@gmail.com", "........") 
message = u"бла бла бла".encode('utf8')
s.sendmail(".....@gmail.com", ".....@gmail.com", message)
```

But I get an error when I do

```
subject = u'бла бла бла'.encode('utf8')
body = u'бла бла бла'.encode('utf8')

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body) 
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("......@gmail.com", ".......")
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    s.quit() 

    print ('Email sent!')
except:
    print ('Something went wrong...')
```

I add

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
subject = MIMEText('текст 1', 'plain') 
body = MIMEText('текст 2', 'plain') 
then again
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("......@gmail.com", ".......")
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    s.quit() 

    print ('Email sent!')
except:
    print ('Something went wrong...')
```

I get the letter but
in subject field

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
```

In body field

```
текст 1
```

i.e in body field I get text from subject. Ho to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add

```
from email.header import Header
Subject= Header('бла бла бла', 'utf-8')
```

Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me

```py
part.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=('utf-8', '', ATTACHMENT_NAME))
```

Complete code sample for sending email with attachment:

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders

ATTACHMENT_NAME = 'отчет.xlsx'

def send_email():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = EMAIL_SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = USERNAME
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(RECIPIENTS)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(EMAIL_TEXT))

    with open(REPORT_FILE, 'rb') as f:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=('utf-8', '', ATTACHMENT_NAME))
        msg.attach(part)
    s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    s.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    s.sendmail(USERNAME, RECIPIENTS, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```